# Could anybody explain me how to include Chromium in an existing XCode-Project?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, chromium, chromium-embedded

I try to include the Chromium embedded Framework to my XCode Project but I can't make it work. 
I read loads of tutorials but nothing really helped me. I am able to build and run the CefSimpleSample but if try to use the libraries from these project there are still files missing.

I did this:

1. Added /PATHTOMYCODE/xcodebuild/Debug/libcef_dll_wrapper.a to the "Other Linker Flags" under Debug.
2. Added for "Search Paths", "Header Search Paths" /SOMEWHERE_WHERE_MY_CEF_BINARY_IS..../chromium/cef_binary, this folder contains the include folder for cef
3. In "Build Phases" tab "Link binary with libraries", added Chromium Embedded Framework.framework

But I am not able to import any cef class. I am really desperated, there isn't one post or tutorial which explains how to add cef to an existing project.

If anybody has experience with Chromium in OSX, please help me :)

Cheers

Comment: what errors are you getting when you try to compile?  or what files are missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Final Solution for my problem:

1. add libcef_dll_wrapper.a to "Other Linker Flags" (Build Settings)
2. add the cef binarie folder which has the include folder in it to"Search Paths", "User Header Search Paths" (Build Settings)
3. add Chromium Embedded Framework.framework to "Link binary with libraries" (Build Phases)
4. add libcef_dll_wrapper.a to "Link binary with libraries" (Build Phases)
5. add the two runscripts called PostBuild "Add Framework" and "Fix Frameworks Links" from CefSimple (Build Phases)
6. add --deep to "Other Code Signing Flags" (Build Settings)
7. change compiler from libc++ to libstdc++ (Build Settings/C++ Standard Library)

Hope I could help someone with it :)

Comment: Do you have a sample project in which you have chromium working in an xCode project that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: No, I am sorry i don't have the project anymore. But i suggest you to use the offical cef sample applications like 'cef simple'. If you alter this application it should be possible for you to create your own application.